# How to show alert if multiple option values are empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, input

I have the following HTML and Javascript, that is not working:

```
<select id="shirtinfo[0]" name="shirtinfo[0]">
    <option value="">Confederation</option>
    <option value="6770">Europe (UEFA)</option>
    <option value="16272">South America (CONMEBOL)</option>
    <option value="21684">Africa (CAF)</option>
    <option value="21771">North &amp; Central America (CONCACAF)</option>
    <option value="18091">Asia (AFC)</option>
    <option value="19193">Oceania (OFC)</option>
</select>
...
<select id="season" name="season">
    <option value="">Season</option>
    <option value="2013">2013</option>
    ...
</select>
...
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="[[Save:raw]]" onclick="validate()" />

<script>
function validate() {
    if  (document.querySelectorAll("#shirtinfo[0], #shirtinfo[1], #shirtinfo[2], #shirtinfo[3], #shirtinfo[4], #season, #style, #status").value)
        {
            alert("[[Please enter the mandatory fields]]");
            return false;
        }
}
</script>
```

All the first option values are empty with just the title, and the alert will be shown if any of the options are not selected. So the user needs to select from the lists at least something else that is not the first option.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: Also in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9f76X/

```
<select id="shirtinfo" name="shirtinfo[0]">
    <option value="">Confederation</option>
    <option value="6770">Europe (UEFA)</option>
    <option value="16272">South America (CONMEBOL)</option>
    <option value="21684">Africa (CAF)</option>
    <option value="21771">North &amp; Central America (CONCACAF)</option>
    <option value="18091">Asia (AFC)</option>
    <option value="19193">Oceania (OFC)</option>
</select>
...
<select id="season" name="season">
    <option value="">Season</option>
    <option value="test">test</option>
</select>
...
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="[[Save:raw]]" onclick="return validate();" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate() {
    var controls, cnt, showAlert;
    controls = document.querySelectorAll("#shirtinfo,#season");

    for (cnt=0;cnt < controls.length; cnt++)
    {
        if (!controls[cnt].value) 
        {
            showAlert = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (showAlert) {
        alert("[[Please enter the mandatory fields]]");
    }
    return !showAlert;
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

Alter the following code as necessary. Just loop through the proper elements, and if the `select`'s value is empty, then break and handle as necessary.

```
function validate() {
    "use strict";
    var selectEls = document.querySelectorAll('select'),
        numSelects = selectEls.length;

    for(var x=0;x<numSelects;x++) {
        if (selectEls[x].value === '') {
            alert('[[Please enter the mandatory fields]]');
            return false;
        }
    }

    // If the code execution reaches this point, all the tests pass
    // ...
}
```

The code *can* be improved, for example, if you want to continue looping through all the elements, and highlight the problem `select` elements, but that is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer, but how can I use this to just some id's in the page. Because I think this goes through ALL the selects that it finds?
EDIT: I'm stupid and didn't see the querySelectorAll, sorry

Comment: Glad I could help. Just modify the querySelectorAll (like you have in your original question), and it should work fine.

Comment: Hello again, unfortunately it does not work for me for some reason, where the answer below does. What can be?

Comment: As you mentioned in your answer, I'd like to know how can one highlight the problematic select element? Like with a highlight fade effect?